# Sequelize can't create table but when I run the same in MySQL CLI it works

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and have run into a weird error:

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `groupname` VARCHAR(255), `groupkey` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `username` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255), `salt` VARCHAR(255), `token` VARCHAR(255), `group_id` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `message` VARCHAR(255), `group_id` INTEGER, `user_id` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE: Can't create table 'crew.users' (errno: 150)
    at module.exports.Query.formatError (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:160:16)
    at Query._callback (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:38:23)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE: Can't create table 'crew.messages' (errno: 150)
    at module.exports.Query.formatError (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:160:16)
    at Query._callback (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:38:23)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/public/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
```

The weird part is, when I try executing those commands in MySQL CLI, it works perfectly:

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `groupname` VARCHAR(255), `groupkey` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `username` VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255), `salt` VARCHAR(255), `token` VARCHAR(255), `group_id` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `message` VARCHAR(255), `group_id` INTEGER, `user_id` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Here is how I am defining the tables:

```
var dbconfig = {};
dbconfig.database = process.env.database || 'crew';
dbconfig.username = process.env.username || 'root';
dbconfig.password = process.env.password || '';
dbconfig.hostname = process.env.hostname || 'localhost';

var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbconfig.database, dbconfig.username, dbconfig.password, {
  host: dbconfig.hostname
});

var User = sequelize.define('users', {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING, 
    unique: true
  },
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
  salt: Sequelize.STRING,
  token: Sequelize.STRING,
  group_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: 'groups',
    referencesKey: 'id'
  }
});

var Message = sequelize.define('message', {
  message: Sequelize.STRING,
  group_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: 'groups',
    referencesKey: 'id'
  },
  user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: 'users',
    referencesKey: 'id'
  }
});

var Group = sequelize.define('groups', {
  groupname: Sequelize.STRING,
  groupkey: Sequelize.STRING
});


Group.sync({force: true});
User.sync({force: true});
Message.sync({force: true});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out!! Hopefully this will help others.

So basically the commands below are async operations, they get executed at different times, resulting in sequelize to fail, since the tables are dependent on other tables, order of execution matters.

```
Group.sync({force: true});
User.sync({force: true});
Message.sync({force: true});
```

Instead of doing the above, if you call `sync()` on `sequelize` instead, sequelize knows exactly what order the commands need to executed in.

```
sequelize.sync();
```

Comment: I was really confused before seeing this. Now it suddenly makes complete sense. Really helped me out as I'm just learning how to use Sequelize.

Comment: I have separate files for each model so where should i call  ```sequelize.sync();```

Comment: @Argon call the sequelize.sync() in your entry file ( app.js )

Answer (score 0):

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
  host,
  port,
  dialect: "postgres",
  logging: false,
  sync: true, //create the table if it not exists
});
```

Comment: did not work for me